# T-SQL Query for extracting multiple column conditions

Tags: sql-server

I need to select all the rows if and only if they have a value 'Y' for all the following columns in sql server.

```
Bike_Racks_Lockers  SHELTERS    Telephone   Lighting    FENCES

        N              N            Y           Y          Y                    
        N              N            N           N          Y                
        N              N            N           N          N                
        Y              Y            Y           Y          Y                
        ?              ?            ?           ?          ?                 
        N              N            N           N          N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from yourtable where Bike_Racks_Lockers = 'Y' and  SHELTERS = 'Y' and 
Telephone = 'Y' and Lighting = 'Y' and FENCES = 'Y'
```

**EDIT:**

In that case, do the checking separately and insert into other table. Example:

```
insert into othertable selct * from yourtable where Bike_Racks_Lockers = 'Y' 

insert into someothertable selct * from yourtable where SHELTER = 'Y'
```

Comment: I need data with Bike_Racks_Lockers = 'Y' then insert it into another table. similarly with other columns. using and in where condition gives me data that is Y for all columns together.

Comment: @kpc, if the answer helped solving your query then consider marking it as answer and do upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ColumnName='Y'` for each column in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT Bike_Racks_Lockers, SHELTERS, Telephone, Lighting, FENCES
FROM [TableName]
WHERE Bike_Racks_Lockers='Y'
AND SHELTERS='Y'
AND Telephone='Y'
AND Lighting='Y'
AND FENCES='Y'
```

However, to be honest I'm not certain what the point of this result set would be?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  Bike_Racks_Lockers = SHELTERS 
       AND Telephone  = Bike_Racks_Lockers
       AND Lighting = Bike_Racks_Lockers 
       AND FENCES = Bike_Racks_Lockers 
       AND Bike_Racks_Lockers = 'Y'
```

Comment: Is there a performance (or other) reason why this is a better answer than Rahul's?

Comment: @Romil, nice idea but `Bike_Racks_Lockers = SHELTERS` ... from where SHELTER is getting the value 'Y'?

Comment: we are checking for Bike_Racks_Lockers  = 'Y', so it will check for SHELTERS  ='Y'

Comment: got the 0 records from this query

Comment: Check whether any of the column have space with 'Y'.